# iOS 4 freezes app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios-simulator, ios4

I have an app that runs on iPad and iPhone running iOS 3.2, but when I try to install it in the simulator it freezes - unresponsive interface (a UIAlertView at this point), no console messages, no crash logged. When I step through, it gets all the way through `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and then stops with this list of calls:

```
#0  0x005c4543 in -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:]
#1  0x005c69a1 in -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:]
#2  0x005d0452 in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:]
#3  0x005c9074 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
#4  0x005cdac4 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent
#5  0x030ceafa in PurpleEventCallback
#6  0x02849dc4 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
#7  0x027aa737 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1
#8  0x027a79c3 in __CFRunLoopRun
#9  0x027a7280 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#10 0x027a71a1 in CFRunLoopRunInMode
#11 0x005c6226 in -[UIApplication _run]
#12 0x005d1b58 in UIApplicationMain
#13 0x000029c0 in main at main.m:14
```

The deployment target is iPhone OS 3.2, the base SDK is iPhone Simulator 4.0. The application does some heavy lifting with audio, but at this point, all that's been done is loading a view controller and some initialization. The problem seems to be with the view controller because when I don't load it, I can at least press a button in the alert view. But I don't know what might be going wrong in the view controller because the app doesn't freeze until it's already there - the view controller's view and the alert view show up, but the alert view doesn't respond.

If I close the app and relaunch it in the simulator, the view and alert view do not load, and the screen is just black.

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks,

Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet - so I'll ask you some questions in here.

1. Have you Reset Content and Settings in the simulator and tried installing it fresh?
2. I see lauchOrientation.  Is this the ipad simulator or the iphone simulator, does it matter?  If ipad, have you tried launching in different orientations on the iPad sim?
3. To clarify, you say iPad and iPhone running iOS3.2, but 3.2 doesn't run on the iPhone.  What exact OS are you using in the physical devices, and what exact scenario in the simulator?
4. What's all happening in that "some initialization"?  Are you using 3rd party library?

Answer (score 0):

if you can post your initialization code it will give us more to go on. try cleaning the build, and put a break point for objc_exception_throw, it may give you a stack trace around what ever is causing the problem.